# Writing matplotlib figure to a buffer, then reading as a file for embedding an image in a PDF

Tags: python, matplotlib, buffer, fpdf

I'm trying to save several matplotlib figures into specific locations in a PDF being created with FPDF. I'd prefer not to have to dump these figures to files and then pull them back in.  The better solution seems to be writing them to a buffer, then reading them back in, but I'm not sure that's possible.

Simplified code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from fpdf import FPDF
from io import BytesIO
import base64

# create figure
fig = plt.figure()

# add plot
ax = pd.Series( [1,3,2] ).plot()

# create bytesio object
bio = BytesIO()        

# save figure to bytesio
fig.savefig(bio, format="png", bbox_inches='tight')

# this works to save the figure to a file
with open("myfile.png", "wb") as file:
    file.write(bio.getvalue())

# create a PDF and set some attributes    
pdf = FPDF(orientation="L", unit="in", format="letter")
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 14)
pdf.add_page()

# try to read the bytesio object as though it's a file
# pdf.image() expects a file name or a URL: https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html
# trying to create a data url with the base64-encoded data inside it

pdf.image( name='data://image/png;base64,' + base64.b64encode(bio.getvalue()).decode() , x=1, y=1, w=3.5, type='png')

# save pdf
pdf.output("mypdf.pdf")
```

Full stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-0ec65d0f583e> in <module>()
     30 # trying to create a data url with the base64-encoded data inside it
     31 
---> 32 pdf.image( name='data://image/png;base64,' + base64.b64encode(bio.getvalue()).decode() , x=1, y=1, w=3.5, type='png')
     33 
     34 # save pdf

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    148                 self.error("No page open, you need to call add_page() first")
    149             else:
--> 150                 return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
    151         return wrapper
    152 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py in image(self, name, x, y, w, h, type, link)
    969                 info=self._parsejpg(name)
    970             elif(type=='png'):
--> 971                 info=self._parsepng(name)
    972             else:
    973                 #Allow for additional formats

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py in _parsepng(self, name)
   1770                f = urlopen(name)
   1771         else:
-> 1772             f=open(name,'rb')
   1773         if(not f):
   1774             self.error("Can't open image file: "+name)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data://image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU  #snipped for length#
```

Since pdf.image() can take a URL, I'd like to construct a data URL that doesn't actually try to open up a file.  It would be like embedding an image inline in an  HTML page. That sort of idea.  I've tried several iterations of getvalue() and encode() and decode(), but I'm not getting the right combination.

I am successfully writing to a file in this example to make sure my BytesIO object has the right data in it, but dumping it into pdf.image() is not working.

Comment: `pdf.image( name=` does not accept **file like objects**. According to the [documentation - image](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html#image) `name` has to be **Path or URL of the image**.

Comment: It's not possible. URLs need to start with `"http"`, else you need a physical file with a filename. I suppose it would be possible to change the fpdf source code to allow for buffered input.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That's what I was afraid of.  I was hoping the term URL was a little looser and could be spoofed into allowed a whole file to be embedded in it like can work in HTML pages.  Data URI scheme...this idea:

`<div>
    <p>Taken from wikpedia</p>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
    9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
</div>`

I'm not married to FPDF.  Is there another library that might be better suited for this?

Comment: You're right, this is somehow a choice of fpdf; but I'm afraid, I don't know other libraries for that matter. However, there seem two more obvious questions: (1) why not use matplotlib directly to create the pdf? (2) In case (1) is not an option, why not simply save the image to disk first?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest What I'm producing is a big combination of text and images.  Each page represents a student, 7 metrics per student.  I want to place the  images in precise locations, and each image is tweaked slightly to show the student's position among peers.  I haven't seen where I can shove the matplotlib figure straight into a PDF without it taking up the whole page.  Question (2) is exactly where I'm headed.  I have 127 students in this list, times 7 graphs is several hundred images.  It works but takes about 3 mins to do the whole thing.

Comment: Note that you can create a matplotlib figure of arbitrary size (e.g. A4 / A5 / "letter") and position the axes inside of it at your desired location. Probably you could then also add text to the thus created pdf in the regions not covered by the figure.  If all of this is about speed, note that saving an image to disk is only *slightly* slower than into memory. I suppose the most time is taken to create the image, which will be the same in both scenarios.

Comment: Ah, this is the best solution. I'm new to matplotlib and didn't quite have the terminology right when I was studying the documentation.  **Figures can have multiple axes.**  And I bet saving the page of 7 axes in 1 figure is going to be faster.