# How do you you insert a plot from Matplotlib.pyplot into an FPDF document?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fpdf

I am trying to make a little (quite simple) script that generates a statistics report. The report should contain a little text, some written statistics (numbers), and some plots from Matplotlib.

I read that FPDF is the one of the best libraries for creating PDF documents

But how do you insert a plot into an FPDF document?

Whenever I try to import a PNG from matplotlib FPDF simply says:

`RuntimeError: FPDF error: Unsupported image type: fig_img1`

Comment: what did you try? have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195075/insert-base64-image-to-pdf-using-pyfpdf)

Answer (score 3):

1. you can save the figures as pictures, then insert pictures in PDF by using FPDF. This is fairly straightforward and you can easily look this up.
2. The alternative is to save the image to a bytesIO object without explicitly dumping it as a png file, then get the FPDF object to read this in. This functionality is not current supported in fpdf, so you will need to implement this functionality yourself.

To do this, consult the following three answers in that order:

[Writing matplotlib figure to a buffer, then reading as a file for embedding an image in a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54376569/writing-matplotlib-figure-to-a-buffer-then-reading-as-a-file-for-embedding-an-i)

[Insert Base64 image to pdf using pyfpdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195075/insert-base64-image-to-pdf-using-pyfpdf)

[load_resource function not found as a class method of FPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59609882/load-resource-function-not-found-as-a-class-method-of-fpdf)